# Debootstrap locales error, unable to install locales to fix it?

Tags: linux

I'm writing a script that downloads various releases using 'debootstrap' and installs some necessary packages on it (including locales), then packages it for use in another script.

I get the following error when running the command inside the chroot:

```
# locale-gen en_US.UTF-8;update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
Generation complete.
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
*** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings:  LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

When I run "export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'" it reports no errors, but it does not fix any issues.

So the question is, how can I fix these locales errors?

PS: I can post part of the script source if it would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid that you are calling `locale-gen` wrong -- `locale-gen` does not take locales as parameters. You need to specify all locales for your system in `/etc/locale.gen`, the call `locale-gen` once to generate them all for you.

**EDIT**: The `/etc/locale.gen` was the file I set when using Debian. I'm using Ubuntu now, and the configuration file is  `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local`. Check your `locale-gen` man page to make sure.

Comment: So would something like `cat "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen` or to the Ubuntu path, then running `locale-gen`, make sense to do?

Comment: Yep, that should do it. What do you get? Check your locale-gen man page to make sure as well.

Comment: @ionFish, it should read `echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen`.

Comment: I get the following error still while installing software to the system: http://fpaste.org/14822/83369136/raw/ . Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't help. Need to see the log of exactly what locale-gen said.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8962/discussion-between-ionfish-and-xpt)

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8962/2013/5/28

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8962